# Resizing Blogger Homepage Images

Tags: blogger

I am a amateur blogger and have been attempting to make the images on my homepage a unified (and smaller than in the post body) size. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Place this codes -

```
.post-body img {
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Just above the `]]></b:skin>` tag.

Note: If `.post-body img` is already present in your Blogger skin tag then simply replace that with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible depending on the blogger template you are using and how your home page design looks. I used to adopt different designs for my blogger templates depending on the category of blogger template... https://weblyb.com/blogger .. Need more info to help you...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how your template sizes up your image on homepage. The quickest solution though (and the most basic) is you may want to use CSS to resize them "if page is homepage"

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
.post-body img {
  width: [PLACE YOUR DESIRED WIDTH];
  height: [PLACE YOUR DESIRED HEIGHT];
}
</b:if>
```

The problem though with this approach is that your image might be stretched or shrink. If that is okay for you then this should work, else, you may need to learn how to edit your own template and set a different code/layout for homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by navigating to theme in your blogger dashboard, click on edit html and find this set of code below:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
.post-body img {
  width: [input you preferred width];
  height: [input your preferred height ];
}
</b:if>
```

Then click on save theme and you are done.